# Mysqladmin (and mysql) can't access database using subdomain

Tags: mysql

I have a remote mysql instance (not on the local machine, but on the same subnet as my testing platform) that I'm using for testing. So that I can mimic the real database in the application, I've modified /etc/hosts with the following two entries:

```
192.168.1.249   macduff
192.168.1.249   dc2-mysql-01.kattare.com
```

Everything works fine when I attempt to access the database remotely using

> mysql -h 192.168.1.249 -u myusername -pThePassword

and

> mysql -h macduff -u myusername -pThePassword

However, when I use

> mysql -h *dc2-mysql-01.kattare.com* -u myusername -pThePassword

The *mysql* monitor seems to connect, but it then hangs. It prints the usual password warning but doesn't print the *Welcome to the MySQL monitor* message, for example. The monitor also doesn't respond to any input. I'm assuming that I've got the user set up properly, given that I can access the instance using the IP address and the single-word alias. I have a single % as the host name associated with the user. If it matters, I'm using a Homebrew install of mysql 5.7.12 on a mac running El Capitan on both the local and remote machines.

MORE INFO:

Just tried creating a user with the dc2... address listed explicitly as a host, but that didn't help (which seems to imply that this isn't a CREATE USER or GRANT issue). I let mysql run for a while, and eventually something timed out and I got a

> ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on
>   'dc2-mysql-01.kattare.com' (60)

Which implies a DNS problem, but the dc2... address works fine in the browser, so it appears to be something mysql related. DNS in mysql is enabled (it recognizes the single-word alias *macduff* without difficulty).

Any idea what's going on?

Comment: There is an option that disables DNS lookups under MySQL. The lookups add overhead. Check the config of the MySQL server. It could also be a DNS config issue or a user grant problem.

Comment: Do you get query output if you add a simple SQL statement with -e? As in `mysql -h dc2-mysql-01.kattare.com -u myusername -pThePassword -e "SELECT * FROM atable WHERE id=123"`

Comment: There is a situation I recall, wherein if the mysqli CLI client cannot detect it has a proper TTY, then it will not appear to accept input. I can't find a relevant answer though.

Comment: I always assumed the hosts file needed the hostnames for a single IP address to be on the same line, like this: `192.168.1.249 macduff dc2-mysql-01.kattare.com`

Comment: -Michael  No, hosts can take multiple entries on one line, but it can handle multiple entries on multiple lines as well (at least I've been doing that for years without difficulty).  I find the multi-line version easier to read, but that's me.  I  I just tried using -e on the mysql command line with no effect---It just hung after the password warning as before.

Comment: However! This time I just let it sit for a few minutes, and eventually something timed out and I got an. 

ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'dc2-mysql-01.kattare.com' (60)

which would seem to point at a dns problem. I can use that URL in the browser to access the machine, so it's almost certainly a mysql config issue.

Comment: I don't think that DNS lookup is disabled as user212349 suggests because it successfully connects when I give it the simple machine name (macduff) in the -h.